# acer aspire es1-531 keyboard issue

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, aspire

I have a persistent issue:

I can't get <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd> + (<kbd>2</kbd>or<kbd>3</kbd>or<kbd>4</kbd>), etc. to work

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> works fine but I can't get any special characters.

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> works, for example.

My laptop is an Acer Aspire es1-531 with a Swiss French Keyboard on Lubuntu 16.04

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Is your keyboard one of those with double-character keys, which you type in the secondary characters by pressing Ctrl + Alt + "Key" in Windows? My Acer laptop's keyboard (PT-BR) has the "Q" and "W" keys with "/" and "?" as secondary characters, and instead of Ctrl + Alt, in Ubuntu, I have to press AltGr (right alt) and the key to get their secondary characters.

This might be the case with your numeric characters as well. Give AltGr + key a try!